# how to do angular sitemap with .net core API?

Tags: .net, angular

How to bind angular routes dynamically from json returned by web api.?

**okay so currently im using this angular Routes to do the navigation and breadcrumb in my angular project like this:**

```
const routes : Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: HomeComponent,
data: {
  text: 'Home',
  nav: true,
  breadcrumbs: true
}
},
{
path: 'references',
component: FetchDataComponent,
data: {
  text: 'References',
  nav: true,
  breadcrumbs: true
},
//children: browseRoutes
},
{
path: 'counter',
component: CounterComponent,
data: {
  text: 'Dashboard',
  nav: true,
  breadcrumbs: true
}
},
{
path: 'administration',
component: AdministrationComponent,
data: {
  text: 'Administration',
  nav: true,
  breadcrumbs: true
},
},
{
path: 'contact',
component: AdministrationComponent,
data: {
  text: 'Contact Us',
  nav: true,
  breadcrumbs: true
},
children: browseRoutes
},
];
```

**but i want to do the routes dynamically which come from API like this:**

```
[
{
    "pagesId": 1,
    "url": "",
    "title": "Home",
    "description": "Home Page",
    "parentsId": null
},
{
    "pagesId": 2,
    "url": "administration",
    "title": "Administration",
    "description": "administration Page",
    "parentsId": 1
}
]
```

**is there any possible way to handle this?**

Comment: Might be quite difficult! `Why?`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i need to do admin module for the all the pages so, the routes need to be dynamic according to the data added by user